# how to use ngrx entity selectors?

Tags: angularjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

im using ngrx entity for my store
the problem i cant select the store entities with selectors.
 i did as the code in this example 
https://github.com/angular-university/angular-ngrx-course/blob/master/src/app/courses/course.selectors.ts

in my situation when i use the select on the store i get the store object and not the entities.

this is my reducer:

[image: reducer]

this is the selectors: 
[image: selectors]

this is the component:
[image]

this is the log from the select on the store, i expected a entities object and im getting this:[image]

this is the store:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is because the selector is wrapped inside a function.

```
const selectAll = () => createSelector(selectFoo, entities.selectAll);
```

Therefore you have to call the function, to get the selector's data instead of the store.

```
this.data = this.store.select(selectAll());
```

But my question is why the selector is wrapped, this isn't really needed. You can do:

```
const selectAll = createSelector(selectFoo, entities.selectAll);
```

And in your component you can use it like you're using right now:

```
this.data = this.store.select(selectAll);
```

For more info, check out my article [NgRx: Parameterized selectors](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/parameterized-selectors)

Comment: im still getting the same output. the object of the store and not the entities.                                  export const selectEstateOwnersState = createFeatureSelector<EstateOwnersState>('estateOwners');
export const selectAllEstateOwners = createSelector(selectEstateOwnersState, fromEstateOwner.selectAll);

Comment: Keep in mind, that the selector returns an observable. If you log the `tblData`, you will get the observable. Use the async pipe in HTML to get the data, or use rxjs operators in the code if you just want to log the data.

Comment: fwiw, the benefit of using the factory approach for selectors is to optimize ngrx's memo/caching behavior for selectors. From the [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#using-selectors-with-props): "In order to correctly memoize the selector, wrap the selector inside a factory function to create different instances of the selector." Also since selectors with props are deprecated, a factory with params will be the new way to do selectors with props.